# AWS Lambda can't send email to a verified SES email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ses

I have a static form-based HTML contact page, where the user needs to drop their Name, email address, subject and message and ultimately my script will reroute all the required value via AWS API --> Lambda --> my Gmail.

So, for that, I have a verified my GMAIL account in SES. And my AWS Lambda function is as below, (here, I used the same confirmed email address for to and send to deliver the email.)

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sesClient = new AWS.SES();
const sesConfirmedAddress = "XXXX@gmail.com";

/**
 * Lambda to process HTTP POST for a contact form with the following body
 * {
      "email": <contact-email>,
      "subject": <contact-subject>,
      "message": <contact-message>
    }
 *
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var emailObj = JSON.parse(event.body);
    var params = getEmailMessage(emailObj);
    var sendEmailPromise = sesClient.sendEmail(params).promise();

    var response = {
        statusCode: 200
    };

    sendEmailPromise.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        callback(null, response);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.statusCode = 500;
        callback(null, response);
    });
};

function getEmailMessage (emailObj) {
    var emailRequestParams = {
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: [ sesConfirmedAddress ]  
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: emailObj.message
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: emailObj.subject
            }
        },
        Source: sesConfirmedAddress,
        ReplyToAddresses: [ emailObj.email ]
    };

    return emailRequestParams;
}
```

Now in IAM, I have created a policy and attached to this lambda function. Then I have created API to use this function to serve my purpose.

Now when I click the TEST button in API, it gives me return code 200. which is great. But the problem is **I don't see any email in my verified Gmail account.**

I'm using, this as my test message,

```
{
      "email": XXXX@example.com,
      "subject": Test,
      "message": This is a Test message
    }
```

I tried also using postman and postman says everything is fine with 200 as return code. But still **no email to my Gmail account**. I checked in cloud watch logs everything is Green. So no idea why my verified Gmail is not receiving any kind of test message. Can anyome shed any lights here?

customized Role looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendTemplatedEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Found the problem, there is no problem. It's was dumping in the SPAM folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would you recommend two things, first try to deploy your code using [serverless framework](https://serverless.com) which can [help](https://forum.serverless.com/t/enabling-aws-ses-in-serverless-yml/2358) you with the dependencies like IAM roles.

Second, As an alternative and complementary steps you may use the following [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dashboardtestlambdafunction.html) from AWS:

1. Open the Amazon SES console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/.
2. In the column on the left, choose either Email Addresses or Domains.
3. Select a verified email address or domain, and then choose Send a
4. Test Email. For To:, type bounce@simulator.amazonses.com. For
   Subject and Body, type some sample text. Choose Send Test Email.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 to create another test message, but this time,
   for To:, type complaint@simulator.amazonses.com.
6. Open the Amazon SQS
   console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/sqs/. The Messages
   Available column should indicate that 2 messages are available.

Answer (score 1):

can you print the complete response to see if you get message id in the response ? if so, there seems to be no problem with the permission.
1. You can enable SNS notification for Bounce/Delivery/complaint for the verified identity in SES console  and see if you receive any notification after making sendmail api call.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-sns.html

2. Additionally, also check recipient spam box.

Comment: This is working fine, it's in my SPAM folder. However, I have implemented the suggestion adding notification via SNS. Thanks.